# How to populate Python dictionary using a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

I am trying to populate this dictionary as I loop through, however when I print it to check, it seems like only the only element being added to the dictionary is the last item in the for loop. How can this be done?

```
probabilities = {}
with tf_Session(graph=graph) as sess:
results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                  {input_operation.outputs[0]:t})
results = np.squeeze(results)

top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
labels = load_labels(label_files)
for j in top_k:
    print(labels[j], results[j])
    probabilities = {labels[j]:results[j]}

print (probabilities)
```

Comment: `probabilities[labels[j]] = results[j]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for adding an element to a `dict`. You are just reseting the `dict` each time. You probably want

```
probabilities[labels[j]] = results[j]
```

instead of

```
probabilities = {labels[j]:results[j]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new dict here in every iteration,

```
probabilities = {labels[j]:results[j]}
```

this should be

```
probabilities[labels[j]] = results[j]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating a new dictionary in each iteration of your loop. Try the following:

```
probabilities = {}
for j in top_k:
   print(labels[j], results[j])
   probabilities[labels[j]] = results[j]
```