# Populate a list of python dictionaries with for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to populate a list a dictionaries with a for loop, but the final result shows that the last dictionary populated by the for loop, overwrites the values of all the previous dictionaries. I've tried to adapt the solution proposed in: [How to populate Python dictionary using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600007/how-to-populate-python-dictionary-using-a-loop) to my code, but I'm still getting the same result.

I've used `.append()` in the past with list objects, but I'm not sure why the dictionary is overwritten at each iteration. Here is a reproducible example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
my_list1 = [{'x1':1, 'x2':2.4, 'x3':3}, {'x1':4.5, 'x2':5, 'x3':6}, {'x1':7.9, 'x2':8.3, 'x3':9},  {'x1':3, 'x2':0.3, 'x3':4}]
list_test = []
foo = {}

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):

        if isinstance(list(my_list1[i].values())[j], float) and  list(my_list1[i].values())[j] > 0.1:    
            foo[list(my_list1[i].keys())[j]] = [float(x) for x in np.linspace(start = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] - 0.5,  stop = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] + 0.5, num = 3)]
    
        elif isinstance(list(my_list1[i].values())[j], int) and  list(my_list1[i].values())[j] > 0.1:    
            foo[list(my_list1[i].keys())[j]] = [float(x) for x in np.linspace(start = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] - 0.5,  stop = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] + 0.5, num = 3)]
           
    list_test.append(foo)
```

The actual output of `list_test`  when you run the above code is:

```
[{'x1': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5], 'x2': [-0.2, 0.3, 0.8], 'x3': [3.5, 4.0, 4.5]},
 {'x1': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5], 'x2': [-0.2, 0.3, 0.8], 'x3': [3.5, 4.0, 4.5]},
 {'x1': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5], 'x2': [-0.2, 0.3, 0.8], 'x3': [3.5, 4.0, 4.5]},
 {'x1': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5], 'x2': [-0.2, 0.3, 0.8], 'x3': [3.5, 4.0, 4.5]}]
```

But I'm expecting to see :

```
[{'x1': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5], 'x2': [1.9, 2.4, 2.9], 'x3': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5]},
 {'x1': [4.0, 4.5, 5.0], 'x2': [4.5, 5.0, 5.5], 'x3': [5.5, 6.0, 6.5]},
 {'x1': [7.4, 7.9, 8.4], 'x2': [7.8, 8.3, 8.8], 'x3': [8.5, 9.0, 9.5]},
 {'x1': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5], 'x2': [-0.2, 0.3, 0.8], 'x3': [3.5, 4.0, 4.5]}]
```

Any advice to achieve the solution will be appreciated.

Comment: can u explain how that output is achieved ? Explain your logic used to change input to expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `foo` in your code (a dictionary) is a mutable type, in every row all the modifications that you do to it, you do it to the same dictionary.

So if I put it simply what your code does is

for eg.

```
list1 = []

foo = {'a':1,'b':2}

list1.append(foo)

# list1 now is [foo]

foo['b'] = 3

list1.append(foo)

# list1 now is [foo, foo]
# i.e. [{'a':1,'b':3}, {'a':1,'b':3}]
```

The solution to your problem, initialize a new dictionary foo at the start of every row modification:

```
my_list1 = [{'x1':1, 'x2':2.4, 'x3':3}, {'x1':4.5, 'x2':5, 'x3':6}, {'x1':7.9, 'x2':8.3, 'x3':9},  {'x1':3, 'x2':0.3, 'x3':4}]
list_test = []

for i in range(4):
    foo = {}
    for j in range(3):

        if isinstance(list(my_list1[i].values())[j], float) and  list(my_list1[i].values())[j] > 0.1:    
            foo[list(my_list1[i].keys())[j]] = [float(x) for x in np.linspace(start = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] - 0.5,  stop = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] + 0.5, num = 3)]
    
        elif isinstance(list(my_list1[i].values())[j], int) and  list(my_list1[i].values())[j] > 0.1:    
            foo[list(my_list1[i].keys())[j]] = [float(x) for x in np.linspace(start = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] - 0.5,  stop = list(my_list1[i].values())[j] + 0.5, num = 3)]
           
    list_test.append(foo)
```

Output:

```
>>> list_test

[{'x1': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5], 'x2': [1.9, 2.4, 2.9], 'x3': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5]}, 
{'x1': [4.0, 4.5, 5.0], 'x2': [4.5, 5.0, 5.5], 'x3': [5.5, 6.0, 6.5]}, 
{'x1': [7.4, 7.9, 8.4], 'x2': [7.8, 8.3, 8.8], 'x3': [8.5, 9.0, 9.5]}, 
{'x1': [2.5, 3.0, 3.5], 'x2': [-0.2, 0.3, 0.8], 'x3': [3.5, 4.0, 4.5]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put this `foo = {}` right after the line `for i in range(4):`